# Delete rows in text file

Tags: powershell

Exporting or deleting of the specific rows. My big text file (structure: date, url, title):

```
2018-11-23 15:03:06;$https://super.cz;$Super.cz
2018-11-26 14:09:06;$https://novinky.cz;$Novinky
2018-11-26 15:13:06;$https://denik.cz;$
2018-11-27 08:06:13;$https://www.google.com;$Google.com
etc.
```

Desired structure of text file (deleting of the third and other row):

```
2018-11-23 15:03:06;$https://super.cz;$Super.cz
2018-11-26 14:09:06;$https://novinky.cz;$Novinky
2018-11-27 08:06:13;$https://www.google.com;$Google.com
etc.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just read the file and drop lines that end with `;$`, then write the modified content back to the file.

```
$file = 'C:\path\to\your.csv'
(Get-Content $file) | Where-Object {
    $_ -notlike '*;$'
} | Set-Content $file
```

Note that the parentheses around the `Get-Content` call are required here, because you need to finish reading the entire file first before writing back to the same file (otherwise you'd end up with an empty file).